# How to know if computational calculations are correct

Tags: computational-chemistry

I've recently been modelling some transition states of a reaction I've been doing (read: struggling to do).

Whilst I have a lot of technical support in doing this (both step by step help and also academics who research in the field of computational chemistry), one thing that bugs me is the difficulty in knowing whether the calculation is meaningful.

In synthetic chemistry, I can do an experiment, then take an NMR/crystal structure, and be confident that i've got what I was intending to do. Whilst different bases may promote different reactions, its always possible to work out whats happened.

In computational chemistry, I do a calculation and get an answer, however depending on the methods used the answer might change.

This can be minimal: isomer A is favoured over isomer B, but the extent changes depending on the basis set/experiment. Or can be significant: isomer A and B change their order.

I was wondering if there is any way of telling whether a calculation is relevant. Obviously experiment can do this, but the reason I'm doing the calculation to begin with is to try and rationalise the difficulties in reaction .

Is there a concrete way to quantify the 'meaningfulness' of a computational result, or is it always a case of just fitting the computational data to experiment and then working backwards.

Comment: While I don't know how to correctly use computational methods myself, sometimes I get support from a friend of mine who studies in the computational field. I haven't read much material so far, but he told me that each method has a certain degree of precision (for example, in terms of energies).
So, I think that if the results that you get fall under this degree of precision they are not reliable, but I hope that someone can give you a more quantitative answer.

Comment: The computational calculations are generally correct (your input is a well defined question and you get a correct answer to that in the given framework). What you should worry more if your model is correct (ie if you asked the correct question): what is the accuracy of the method, what kind of errors and correction one can expect, what effects are negligible what effects are not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only guaranteed way to achieve absolute correctness is to use asymptotically better methods and see the asymptotic behavior yourself. This, however, ofter requires prohibitively complex approaches.

Outside of that, one needs an experiment to check your data against. A good way (with limits) is to perform vibration frequency calculations and see if that fit the experiment. (making correction of unharmonic behavior). Another way is to run through similar well-studied cases and fit computational results. Most probably, a systematic error would be found, that can be easily eliminated. Luckily, most probably you are not the first to work with your particular kind of systems, so using google scholar it is usually possible to find a review or an establishing work that would list what work and what does not. Most practical methods have known 'glitches', and the ways to deal with them were considered. In particular, DFT cannot catch dispersion interactions, requiring empirical correction schemes.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your question I guess you are doing some sort of quantum calculations on small molecules, most likely DFT. (Please, correct me if I am wrong. Also, I'm not a fan of DFT, so my answer can be a bit biased...) In this case, knowing if the "numbers" you get are correct it's not too easy.

What I would check is how sensitive are your results on the setting of the calculation. In the case of the two isomers, for example, does the order of stability change if you use bigger basis sets or if you change the DFT functional? If you get always the same answer then you can be reasonably sure that answer is correct. If instead, you get a set of unreasonable results, then you should question all results, and try to understand (i.e. search the literature) which method is best for your particular problem.

For other computational methods such as ab-initio methods, semiempirical methods, or classical force fields, very different ways of checking the results exist, which is quite difficult to list them all.